# Import sql query on ODBC table in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

Using MS Access 2007 I would like to retrieve only part of an ODBC table.
I can import the whole table in Access but I don't need all of it and it would be a waste of space and performance to store the whole table when I only need certain columns.

In Excel I wrote a SQL query that let me retrieve only the part I'm interested in. What I'd like to know is: is it possible to import only the result of a SQL query in Access or do I have to retrieve the whole table and then run the query on it?

Is it possible using built-in Access module or should I turn to VBA?

Edit: Basically I would like to run the ODBC data connection below (currently used in Excel) in Access.

Connection string:

```
DSN=BLA1;
UID=BLA2;
DBQ=BLA3;
PWD=BLA4;
DBA=W;
APA=T;
EXC=F;
FEN=T;
QTO=T;
FRC=10;
FDL=10;
LOB=T;
RST=T;
GDE=F;
FRL=F;
BAM=IfAllSuccessful;
MTS=F;
MDI=F;
CSR=F;
FWC=F;
PFC=10;
TLO=0;
```

Command string:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST TEST
WHERE (TEST.DATE_STAMP=?)
```

When I try to link the database I get the error `The database engine can't find 'WTD.DATAPOINT_5/1000'. Make sure it is a valid parameter or alias name, that it doesn't include characters or punctuation, and that the name isn't too long.` but when I use the Excel database connection I get no error and everything is updated.

Comment: Do you know where `DATAPOINT_5/1000` comes from? Is it a column name in a Table? Or maybe it is column formula in a View (dividing `DATAPOINT_5` by 1000)? I'm still confused.... :(

Comment: I can tell you that it's not a column but other than this I can't tell you much. I have no idea where it comes from but what I'm sure of is that using excel to retrieve the data I don't get any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to *import* the whole table. You could *link* to the ODBC table and then run a make-table query against that linked table to copy in only the rows and columns that you need.

Comment: I just tried linking it but I get the error: "The database engine can't find 'WTD.DATAPOINT_5/1000'. Make sure it is a valid parameter or alias name, that it doesn't include characters or punctuation, and that the name isn't too long."

Comment: @Leo I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit your question with more details. Have you created an ODBC DSN? Are you getting the error when you try to create the linked table in Access? Or is it when you try to run the make-table query, and if so what does the query look like?

Comment: I just edited the question. I hope things are clearer now, if not, let me know!